# Using jQuery multiselect to add values to url hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following multi-select control needs to be used to update a url hash containing a comma-separated list of ids.

```
<select id="options" multiple>
    <option id="1">Option 1</option>
    <option id="2">Option 2</option>
    <option id="3">Option 3</option>
    <option id="4">Option 4</option>
    <option id="5">Option 5</option>
    <option id="6">Option 6</option>
    <option id="7">Option 7</option>
</select>
```

In the example below, Options 2, 3, and 4 are selected in the multi-select control. Selecting and un-selecting options in the multi-select control should update the url hash accordingly.

```
http://localhost/index#options=2,3,4
```

I have created a fiddle with the multi-select control but do not know how best to approach the url hash change. I have tried using an href to change the hash but that is not supported within an option tag, and does not provide the logic needed to update the hashes accordingly.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/acreton/Bu52L/)

Please let me know if I provide any additional information.

Comment: +1 for a complete question with relevent code, what is required, and a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Bu52L/1/)

Ok without interfering with any of that plugin code

First you need to address your options

```
use this: <option value="1">Option 1</option>
not this: <option id="1">Option 1</option>
```

Then this jQuery will do what you want.

```
 $('#options').on('change', function(){
     var val=$(this).val();
     if (val) hash=val.join(','); // join fails if .val() is null (nothing selected)
     else hash='';
     window.location.hash=hash;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Part of your issue is that in JSFiddle you won't be able to see the hash.

That said if you listen for changes on the `<select>` you can concatenate the array of values into a string using `join()` and then set this as a has using  `window.location.hash`.

You could so something like this (based on @popnoodles code)

```
$( '#options' ).on( 'change', function() {
    window.location.hash = $( this ).val().join( ',' );
});
```

Comment: @popnoodles thanks for the feedback, I was hoping to do so in an edit.